How can I tell which ZFS snapshots are affected by an error?
A recent scrub of my ZFS pool uncovered one error:
$ zpool status -v rpool
  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
        corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
        entire pool from backup.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 04:48:04 with 1 errors on Thu Oct 24 14:07:21 2024
config:

        NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        rpool                                           ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz1-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
            wwn-0x50014ee216641349-part2                ONLINE       0     0     2
            wwn-0x50014ee216620a52-part2                ONLINE       0     0     2
            wwn-0x50014ee2c1015982-part2                ONLINE       0     0     2
          raidz1-1                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD3000FYYZ-01UL1B1_WD-WCC1F0293326  ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD30EZRZ-00Z5HB0_WD-WCC4N2ZYKAKR    ONLINE       0     0     0
            ata-WDC_WD30EZRZ-60Z5HB0_WD-WCC4N0SFH6JA    ONLINE       0     0     0
        logs
          ata-CT500MX500SSD1_2344E8835E4F-part1         ONLINE       0     0     0
        cache
          sdi2                                          ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: Permanent errors have been detected in the following files:

        rpool/[DATASET]@autosnap_2024-09-30_23:30:07_weekly:[FILEPATH]

(Note: the actual filesystem and file paths are redacted for privacy, but the snapshot name is real.)
Obviously, the error is present in the "autosnap_2024-09-30_23:30:07_weekly" snapshot. However, since ZFS is copy-on-write and this file presumably has not changed in some time, I expect that this error also exists in the versions of this file present in other snapshots. However, the zpool status command does not give me any indication of this. Is there something I can do to determine which snapshots have the corrupted copy of the file in them and which ones do not?

Does that file and that version of its contents exist in any other snapshots or the actual filesystem itself?  It seems somewhat strange to me that if this file with those contents exists outside of this one snapshot, those don't also show the same corruption.

@AndrewHenle That is exactly the question I'm asking. Or rather, I'm asking how to determine the answer.

Remove the file containing the errors listed in the output.
I don't think there's any other course of action needed.

I've already restored the affected file from backup, but I would still like to know if there is a way to determine which of the multiple snapshots contain the corrupted file and which ones don't. (And also, whether the current non-snapshot dataset contains the corrupted file.)

You can also remove the snapshot and run a scrub.

That would presumably just find the same error in one other snapshot containing the same corrupted copy of the file. If there are many snapshots affected, this approach would take weeks to identify and remove all affected snapshots, and in any case I don't necessarily want to remove all these snapshots, just identify which snapshots are affected.

If multiple snapshots were impacted, they would be reflected in the zpool status -v output.

That has not been my experience (on Ubuntu, specifically). Generally, for each instance of corruption, I only see one file in one snapshot listed. But if I delete that snapshot and scrub again, the same checksum error is found in the same file in another snapshot. (Also, the md5sum trick in the answer I posted clearly shows that multiple snapshots are affected while zpool status -v shows just one.)

One simple way I have found to identify all snapshots in which a specific file is corrupted (i.e., has a checksum error) is to try to run a command like md5sum on the same file in every snapshot, e.g.:
md5sum rpool[DATASET]/.zfs/snapshot/*/[FILEPATH]
# Also check the current copy
md5sum rpool[DATASET]/[FILEPATH]

Whatever command you choose should involve reading every byte of the file, which is why I chose a checksum program. For any snapshot with a corrupted copy, this will give an I/O error of some kind, and for any snapshot with no corruption in the specified file, it will simply print the md5sum as normal. However, this is not a general solution, since the file could also have been renamed or moved to another folder, in which case the above shell wildcard will not identify the file in all snapshots. So a solution that directly checks which snapshots still refer to the corrupted copy of the data would still be preferable.
